# Inherting test cases in Python nosetests

Tags: python, nosetests

I have a nose testcase already written and want to inherit the same object for another test case as I'm going to change just one parameter.

So, just to understand how it works I tried to simulate the following using 2 classes `NoseTesting` and `NoseTestingInherit`.

When I run this:

1. I don't see the print statement being printed.
2. When I run the code I get the following result:

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
   ```

I'm not sure which test method ran - Is it `test_this_method_dup` or `test_this_method`?

```
class NoseTesting():
    def test_this_method_dup():
        print "Test this method"

class NoseTestingInherit(NoseTesting):
    def test_this_method():
        print "Test this method"
```

New Code:-

```
import unittest
class NoseTesting(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_this_method_dup(self,):
        print "Test this method"


class NoseTestingInherit(NoseTesting):
    def test_this_method(self,):
        print "Test this method"
```

Output
:

```
test_this_method_dup (nosetesting.NoseTesting) ... ok
test_this_method (nosetesting.NoseTestingInherit) ... ok
test_this_method_dup (nosetesting.NoseTestingInherit) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.003s

OK
```

Comment: It looks like neither of your test classes are being detected as having test cases. I'm not familiar with nose tests, are you supposed to inherit from some `TestCase` base class, or name your test classes in some special way so the test framework recognizes them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IanAuld said, `nosetest` did not discover your tests. According to your example, you need not explicitly rewrite the method if you're not overriding the method since it's implicitly inherited.

```
class NoseTesting(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_this_method_dup(self):
        print "Test this method"

class NoseTestingInherit(NoseTesting):
    # implicitly inherit test_this_method_dup()
    # self.test_this_method_dup()
```

Comment: After I inherit it, I see 3 runs in my output. I have given the latest code above...I'm not sure why test_this_method_dup runs twice..

Comment: @user1050619 Inheritance makes nosetest run duplicate tests. Follow this link http://erikzaadi.com/2012/09/13/inheritance-within-python-unit-tests/ to use magic properties to ignore base tests.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`nosetest`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-classes) docs:

> A test class is a class defined in a test module that matches **testMatch or is a subclass of unittest.TestCase**.

Your classes do not match that pattern.